# how to get key values from Object in JS

Tags: javascript

i have object which contains list of values like key=value. how to get key and value in JS.

```
[Object { name1="value1",  name2="value2", }]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: use dot notation? `object.name1` `object.name2`

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of string with all keys.

Answer (score 3):

To get the keys

```
Object.keys(yourObject)
```

To get single value from object

```
yourObject.key
```

Comment: And to get all values you can use `var values = Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key) { return yourObject[key]; });`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can access each key individually without iterating as in:

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal', second: 'otherVal' };
alert(Object.keys(obj)[0]); // returns first
alert(Object.keys(obj)[1]); // returns second
```

**Solution 2**

You would iterate inside the object with a for loop:

```
for(var i in foo){
  alert(i); // alerts key
  alert(foo[i]); //alerts key's value
}
```

**Solution 3**

If you want to get all keys, ECMAScript introduced [Object.keys](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.3.14). This is only supported by newer browsers but the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) provides an alternative implementation (which also uses for...in btw):

```
if(!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
     if (o !== Object(o))
          throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
     var ret=[],p;
     for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) ret.push(p);
     return ret;
}
```

Of course if you want both, key and value, then for...in is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {name1:"value1",  name2:"value2"}
```

Having an object like this you can get value for each property by using two methods:

*First:*

```
obj.name1;
```

*Second:*

```
obj["name1"];
```

If you want to have an array containing object keys use:

```
var arrayObjKeys = Object.keys(obj);
```

And an array containing object values use:

```
var arrayObjValues = Object.values(obj);
```

As with mentioned everywhere you can not get an associative array from the object cause: **JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes.** So you can either use object and treat them like named associative arrays or store keys and values separately and work on those.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the values of your Object, you need to do the following:

```
Object.name1 // => "value1"
Object.name2 // => "value2"
```

More infos about objects here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {someKey: 'someValue'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log({key, value: obj[key]}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approaches.

The first could be a simple `for` loop

```
var obj = { name1:"value1",  name2:"value2" };
for(let key in obj)
{
    let value = obj[key];
    console.log("Key:", key, " - ", "Value:", value);
}
```